# Import csv issue with characters

Tags: java, csv, character-encoding

When I import CSV file that contains some countries, then I have a problem with some characters. It doesn't encode it well and then I get? mark instead of the character that is written in CSV file.
Here are countries which make me this problem: ÅLAND ISLANDS, SAINT BARTHÉLEMY, CÔTE D'IVOIRE, CURAÇAO.

**Here is code for importing csv file:**

```
ICsvBeanReader beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                    new CsvPreference.Builder(CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE).useQuoteMode(new AlwaysQuoteMode()).build());
```

first i used FileReader and there was problem with all of these countries, then i change to InputStreamReader and add this UTF-8 charset and problem was almost solved. When i use charset UTF-8 i have problem only with reading this country "ÅLAND ISLANDS", as result i get "?LAND ISLANDS".
As charset i've also tried ISO_8859_1, Windows-1252 but it's always same problem with "ÅLAND ISLANDS".

Does anyone know which charset i should use to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know how the csv file is encoded? Just match it to the charset.

Comment: also try `InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"))`

Comment: Seems that this is not an programming issue but rather an encoding issue of the file. You should ensure that your file source is using the correct encoding. From your problematic it seems that parts are encoded with UTF8 and some other parts with ANSI or something else.

Comment: If you really want to find which charsets looks OK, you could iterate over the  StandartCharsets enum, each time selecting the next one and using it to parse the csv, then print the problematic string and the charset name - and there you'll see which one works

Comment: @GuyKhmel file use UTF-8 for encoding, i've tried using "UTF8" and it also doesn't read properly "ÅLAND ISLANDS".

Comment: If that's a static csv file, try to open it and save it again under a different encoding (or do the same process again, with UTF8)

Comment: @GuyKhmel i've tried taht, save again with UTF8, then close file and open again and when i open it was changed with ? mark

Comment: I found this command for unix:

`$ file -I unknown-encoding.csv` which returns 
`unknown-encoding.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-16le`

Comment: http://codeftw.blogspot.co.il/2009/07/how-to-find-character-encoding-of-text.html

Answer (score 0):

Java File reader doesn't handle Byte order mark. I hope that's the issue.

Different of versions handles it differently.

Wrap input stream with the below method.Which detects file type.This method is available in commons-io.If you don't have commons-io grab code from that library.It  will be around 10 to 20 lines.Hope that works.

```
    public static InputStreamReader getInputStreamReader(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException
    {
        BOMInputStream bOMInputStream = new BOMInputStream(inputStream, false, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8,
               ByteOrderMark.UTF_16BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_16LE,
               ByteOrderMark.UTF_32BE, ByteOrderMark.UTF_32LE);
        ByteOrderMark bom = bOMInputStream.getBOM();
        String charsetName = bom == null ? "UTF-8" : bom.getCharsetName();
        return new InputStreamReader(bOMInputStream, charsetName);
    }
```